# windows 8.1 - simple setup that do not require admin right but prompting for User account control

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1

I have windows 8.1 with standard user account when I run simple setup that don't require admin right but prompting for **user account control** which runs perfectly in widows 7 standard user. Even sometimes if I run exe(non-admin) It prompts for **user account control**.

I Want to run exe/setup without prompting user account control in standard user.

Comment: Are you sure your Windows 7 machine had it's UAC set to the same level as your Windows 8.1 machine? how many different machines (both Windows 7 and 8.1) have you actually tried this on?  Have you spoken with the author of the program you're trying to install to determine why it needs elevation?

Comment: maybe Windows 8.x has a never heuristic to check if a program needs admin right or not.

Comment: I have one setup(can be installed other than progra~1) which I can run in Standard user in windows 7, but Same setup in win 8.1 ask me for credential if I choose cancel in authentication nothing happens

Comment: Whoever down rated this question, is not fare at all b'coz I haven't ask non-logical, out of scope question here. I have posted what I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I would cehck that you are 100% sure you don't need admin rights on windows 8.1.

The list of actions which require admin rights has been extended in windows 8.1 and can include a lot of things:

- Allowing a process to write to the root of C:, C:\windows, C:\Program Files (and x86)
- Write to the Registry
- Write to the all users start menu/desktop
- Write to certain areas of a users profile (cant remember which exactly)

..there are more, google is your friend.

Comment: I am 100% sure, B'coz Setup just need to write to disk I just need to give different path where I could Write e.g. Other partition.